# How to recover my pc or accidentally deleted username

Tags: windows-7

In my Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, I was deleting unused usernames in Advanced Profile management window (I could not remember the exact name but there were three buttons: Add, Remove, Properties) which others have created temporarily.

Since I was using shortcut key for Remove button I didn't stop pressing the shortcut key while my username also came to selection and got deleted, furthermore I pressed the OK button for the confirmation dialog box. So tried to recover in the hope of it will be recovered, I create the username account with same username by Computer->Right Click->Manage->Local Users and Groups->Users.

When I restart I realized I no longer have administrator rights. So whenever I try to do administrator things (My password accepts on login, but not when I try to change password in control panel) it asks username and password with administrator privilege.

I am using Dell GX620 PC. I've disabled DVD/USB for standard users. So now I even not able to insert DVD to reinstall the OS.

So How can I retrieve my username or format the OS in this situation?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. From what I read, this is a statement with no question.

Comment: @Ramhound In the link you gave, the accepted answer assumes we do it in administrator privileged user.

Comment: @Dhay - **You are absolutely incorrect.**  My answer to the duplicate question can be implemented provided you can boot to WinRE.  **It does not** require you to have existing Administrator permissions on the machine.  That is the entire point of the answer, to explain how you can get Administrator access, when there are no other Administrator accounts that exist.  If you never had Administrator access, and are not authorized to use the built-in account, then talk an Administrator that does have authorization.

Comment: But as I mentioned I have disabled DVD/USB for standard users before I did this crazy thing

Comment: @Dhay - You made no mention of that in the original revision of the question.  You are also not a standard user, so I would hope you have access, not that it matters because you are booting to an installation disk where a group policy wouldn't be used.  You are going to have to enable DVD/USB access in order to resolve this problem.

Comment: "So How can I retrieve my username or format the OS in this situation?" - You deleted all your Administrator users, this cannot be fixed, unless you gain access to the built-in Administrator.  **You deleted the user profile, it is gone, there is no way to recover the profile that was deleted.**  Follow the instructions in the duplicate question to resolve the problem you created.